# memory leak in qt emitting const container&

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I just wrote a Qt program. I found my program is leaking memory. I have checked extremely carefully for every variable create in the heap. And I finally realize that the cause may be due to emitting a QMap reference by an QObject.

Therefore, I wrote another simple program to demonstrate the leak. This is just a gui with a button. When the button is clicked, a `QList` is generated in a QObject on the stack. the `QList` is then emitted back.
This is all the code.

main.cpp: (just for reference)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

#include "mythread.h"
#include "myobject.h"

typedef QList<long double> doubleList;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void buttonClicked();
    void receiveResult(const doubleList&);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "GUI Thread ID: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::buttonClicked);

    qRegisterMetaType<doubleList>("doubleList");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    MyThread* thread = new MyThread;
    MyObject* object = new MyObject;

    object->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, &MyThread::started, object, &MyObject::jobStart);
    connect(object, &MyObject::jobDone, this, &MainWindow::receiveResult);
    connect(object, &MyObject::jobDone, thread, &MyThread::quit);
    connect(thread, &MyThread::finished, object, &MyObject::deleteLater);
    connect(thread, &MyThread::finished, thread, &MyThread::deleteLater);
    thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::receiveResult(const doubleList &)
{
    qDebug() << "Received result";
}
```

mythread.h (Do nothing, just subclass to make dtor print debug message)

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    MyThread();
    ~MyThread();
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread()
{
    qDebug() << "MyThread ctor, thread ID:\t" << currentThreadId();
}

MyThread::~MyThread()
{
    qDebug() << "MyThread dtor, thread ID:\t" << currentThreadId();
}
```

myobject.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

typedef QList<long double> doubleList;

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyObject();

signals:
    void jobDone(const doubleList&);

public slots:
    void jobStart();
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H

#include "myobject.h"

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "MyObject ctor. MyObject pointer:\t" << this
                << "\tThread ID:\t" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    qRegisterMetaType<doubleList>("doubleList");
}

MyObject::~MyObject()
{
    qDebug() << "MyObject dtor and list deleted. MyObject pointer:\t" << this
             << "\tThread ID:\t" << QThread::currentThreadId();
}

void MyObject::jobStart()
{
    doubleList list;
    qDebug() << this << "jobStart() called. Thread ID:\t" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    for (int i = 0; i != 100000000; ++i)
    {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    emit jobDone(list);
}
```

Debug output:

```
MyThread ctor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject ctor. MyObject pointer:     MyObject(0xbc03a0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject(0xbc03a0) jobStart() called. Thread ID:     0x7f3d9e6df700
Received result
MyObject dtor and list deleted. MyObject pointer:    MyObject(0xbc03a0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3d9e6df700
MyThread dtor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyThread ctor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject ctor. MyObject pointer:     MyObject(0xbafca0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject(0xbafca0) jobStart() called. Thread ID:     0x7f3d9e6df700
Received result
MyObject dtor and list deleted. MyObject pointer:    MyObject(0xbafca0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3d9e6df700
MyThread dtor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyThread ctor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject ctor. MyObject pointer:     MyObject(0xbc03a0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3dbbbf1780
MyObject(0xbc03a0) jobStart() called. Thread ID:     0x7f3d9e6df700
Received result
MyObject dtor and list deleted. MyObject pointer:    MyObject(0xbc03a0)     Thread ID:   0x7f3d9e6df700
MyThread dtor, thread ID:    0x7f3dbbbf1780
```

After clicking the button 3 times, 3GB was hold by the program. There is no heap object created by me. Destructor of each object called. Is this a bug or I am missing something. Could I have some advice.

Comment: There are no memory leaks. Passing arguments throught threads via signals/slots cause deep object copy.

Comment: But the case is the 3gb was holding forever. I have no way to clear the already used deep copy object.

Comment: How do you detect, that this memory is hold by your program? Possible it is an effect of memory fragmentation. Because `list::push_back` makes a lot of memory reallocations.

Comment: I use the build in system monitor in ubuntu

Comment: @thuga this is how movetothread way to implement multithreaded. Normally qthread doesn't need to be  implement. I just want to show that the thread is deleted.

Comment: Subclassing of `QThread` is offtopic there. Question is about memory usage. Please, stop this holywar. Agree with @tom, that subclassing is only used for debug output of ctor/dtor.

Comment: You should try making the QList with the new operator, only pass the pointer with signal/slot and handle the delete yourself, this will probably solve the memory issue, but not answer as to why.  It could at least let you know if it's the signal/slot system is causing a copy that is not being released properly.

Comment: @MichaelBoone OMG. I tried emitting the pointer. Memory is still leaking. I am going to make more testing to find out why.

Comment: Finally, i discover that it is platform related. I try to run the same program under windows, there is no memory issue. However, under Ubuntu, memory never be released.